# Set attribute as variable in reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

In reactstrap, I saw some single word attributes, like `active`, `flush`.
How to make them a variable to dynamic bind with dom?

```
<ListGroup>
        <ListGroupItem active>
          <ListGroupItemHeading>List group item heading</ListGroupItemHeading>
          <ListGroupItemText>
          Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.
          </ListGroupItemText>
        </ListGroupItem>
</ListGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single word attributes in JSX actually represent:

```
<ListGroupItem active={true}></ListGroupItem>
```

The `true` value is implicit when represented with just the keyword.

To convert that to a variable:

```
<ListGroupItem active={this.state.active}>
  <ListGroupItemHeading>List group item heading</ListGroupItemHeading>
  <ListGroupItemText>
    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.
  </ListGroupItemText>
</ListGroupItem>
```

Now, the change to `state.active` will also reflect the attribute value for `active`